# eval phase error when using solr php response

Tags: php, solr

We use Solr PHP response to get Solr search results as the following,

```
$php_code = $this->file_get_contents($solr_url);
eval("\$ret_array = " . $php_code . ";");
```

It works fine most time, but occasionally, we see some php phrase errors as the following,

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in ....
```

Looks like Solr PHP respsonse returns some bad data. Eval function did not catch the real search which caused this error, so it's hard to know what happened.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($php_code);`?

Comment: don't know. It only happens occasionally, so it's hard to dump it unless there is a way to catch eval error.

Comment: why don't u use solarium or any other php client of solr?